# Java Using Multiple predicate for anyMatch

Tags: java, java-stream

I am having a `List` of `HashMap` i.e `List<Map<String, Object>> result`. I want to check if some key value is present on this list or not.

For Example:

```
Name      Count 
Marvel    10
DC         0
```

I want that my list of map should contain at least one entry for the above table for that I am using **anyMatch**

```
Assert.assertTrue(
result.stream().anyMatch(
ag -> ( "Marvel".equals(ag.get("Name")) &&  10==(int)ag.get("Count"))
));
```

How can I use multiple Predicates ? I can have a list of 1000 `HashMap`, I just want to check if any two Hash-map from my list contains those two entries.

Comment: Combine them with `||`: `("Marvel".equals(ag.get("Name")) &&  10==(int)ag.get("Count")) || ("DC".equals(ag.get("Name")) &&  0==(int)ag.get("Count"))`. It's not really a second predicate, but one predicate that checks if either those conditions (Marvel,10 OR DC, 0) is true.

Comment: Does one `map` should contain both the entries or any one single entry?

Comment: `map` will contains only one entries , so i need to find at least 2 maps one for first row and other for second row , if no such map found it should fail.

Comment: @Blaze, if only there is first row i.e `Marvel ` and Count=`10` , and no map exist for `DC` , so `Assert` will not fail for this one.

Comment: Are you getting this from a database or something? A `List<Map<String, Object>>` is certainly the wrong data structure to be using in this case. All you need is a `Map<String, Integer>`

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure seems wrong for a start. A `List<Map<String, Object>>`, where each map represents a row and has only one key and one value? You just need a `Map<String, Integer>`. The string is the name, the integer is the count. Remember to give it a meaningful name, e.g. `comicUniverseToSuperheroFrequency`.

With that said, [`Predicate` has an `and` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) which you can use to chain conditions together. It might look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Map<String, Integer> comicUniverseToSuperheroFrequency = /*something*/;

    boolean isMarvelCountTen = comicUniverseToSuperheroFrequency.entrySet().stream()
        .anyMatch(row -> isMarvel().and(isTen()).test(row));
}

private static Predicate<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> isMarvel()
{
    return row -> "Marvel".equals(row.getKey());
}

private static Predicate<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> isTen()
{
    return row -> row.getValue() == 10;
}
```

Comment: When you have a single `Map`, you should use `map.getOrDefault("Marvel", 0) == 10`, instead of iterating over the entire map to search for a single key.

Comment: @Holger I agree, and thanks, but doing so would side-step the question of "How can I use multiple Predicates?"

Comment: You still have to test whether `map.getOrDefault("Marvel", 0) == 10` *and* `map.getOrDefault("DC", -1) == 0`. Besides that, sometimes the answer *is* “you are using the wrong tool for the job”. After all, that’s already what you are saying at the beginning of your answer by suggesting to use only one map instead of a list of maps.